# Configure ssh private key in smartgit

Tags: linux, git, ssh, ubuntu-16.04, smartgit

I'm trying to configure a git repo in SmartGit through a SSH tunnel on Ubuntu 16.04.

I can't configure my private SSH key in SmartGit. I want to use the SmartGit SSH client but the Pereferences->Authentication don't allow me to add a key to use.

When I pull from the remote, I get a 'permission denied' error.

I found windows related topics but nothing on Linux distribs and nothing in SG documentation.

Comment: You need to add your user account's public key in the git provider account. SmartGit is simply a tool.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure to configure the **System SSH client** in the SmartGit preferences.
If you have ssh in your path, you can then export the [`GIT_SSH_COMMAND` environment variable](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#git-codeGITSSHcode) to instruct Git to use the ssh :command of your choice.
In your case, a command which would directly reference your private key

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i /path/to/private/key'
```

Then launch again SmartGit (for it to inherit that new environment variable), and try again your SSH tunnel.